# Asking for change in work profile in same department

Tags: management, career-development

I have completed 2 years in my work profile and my team boss has agreed to change my work profile.
I wish to be part of Research team which is my true interest.
My manager agreed on mail to put me in research team based on my overall good work in the past 2 years

Recently, few people in "IT Software implementation" team have quit and there is a severe staff shortage.
I am extremely good at IT related stuff and my manager now wants to forcibly put in me IT implementation.I am the only guy, good with IT stuff in my department.
As a formal gesture, he gave me a day's time to think on my future team.
However, his body language clearly shows that he doesn't want me the research team at all.

The IT team communicates with Research team and IT team to build new software. My boss is assuring me that IT team would have more learning opportunities.

However, I want to set a career in "research" and not "systems".
How do I politely convince my manager to put in Research team given the genuine shortage in IT team.

Comment: Is it an option for you to leave this company for pursuing in research? Are you afraid of being dismissed if you keep asking for a research job and they don't like it?

Answer (score 2):

As with anything else: you make the case that you would be of more value *to the company* if you were in the research team. Trouble is, it sounds like this is going to be pretty hard - as you say, you're good at the IT stuff and there is a genuine shortage in the IT team.

How I'd approach this:

1. Make it clear to your boss that still want to do research in the long run.
2. Try and negotiate a deal which involves you working in the IT team for now, because you realise that's of value to the company, but with a plan to transition to the research team in the medium term.

Or of course, you start looking for another job where you can do research.

Comment: His boss already agreed on putting him in the research team, and he's going back on his words. Are further promises trustworthy, at this point?

Comment: Times have changed, people on the IT team have quit.